# How should I inherit from `WPF` window class in a class library?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In a class library I have defined the following class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;

namespace mylirary
{
    public class MainWindow : Window
    {

    }
}
```

somewhere in another project I try to instantiate and show the window but this is not possible. It does not have a `Show()` method!

```
var mw = new MainWindow();
mw.Show();
```

Could you please tell me How should I inherit from `WPF` window class in a class library?

```
    Error   9   'mylirary.MainWindow' does not contain a definition for
 'Show' and no extension method 'Show' accepting a first argument of type 
'mylirary.MainWindow' could be found (are you missing a using directive or 
an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: did you reference `PresentationFramework` or another assembly?

Comment: @Carsten that solved the problem. But I'd added the PresentationFramework in the class library `mylibrary`. Why should I add that in the project again?

Comment: because the method is defined there (on the base-class)